# Strip and split at same time in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to split and strip one string at same time. 
I have a file D:\printLogs\newPrintLogs\4.txt and I want to split it that I get only 4.txt and than to strip the .txt and add in string + ".zpr" to get "4.zpr". 
This is the code that I tryed to use:

```
name = str(logfile)
print ("File name: " + name.split('\\')[-1] + name.strip( '.txt' ))
```

But I get this output:

```
File name: 4.txtD:\printLogs\newPrintLogs\4
```

Comment: try remove `+ name.strip( '.txt' )` from the code

Comment: `str.strip('.txt')` does **not** just remove a trailing `.txt` extension. It removes all characters in a *set*; you'd get the exact same result as using `str.strip('tx.')`. If the input was `'tttx.fooxt'`, you'd end up with `'foo'` as the start and end have all their `'t'`, `'x'` and `'.'` characters removed. You'll have to use different techniques (`os.path.splitext()` or slicing, after a `str.endswidth()` test perhaps)  instead.

Answer (score 6):

You're adding too much there. This is all you need:

```
print ("File name: " + name.split('\\')[-1].strip( '.txt' ))
```

Better yet, use the `os` module:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(r'D:\printLogs\newPrintLogs\4.txt'))[0]
'4'
```

Or, split up among several steps, with occasional feedback:

```
>>> import os
>>> name = r'D:\printLogs\newPrintLogs\4.txt'
>>> basename = os.path.basename(name)
>>> basename
'4.txt'
>>> splitname = os.path.splitext(basename)
>>> splitname
('4', '.txt')
>>> splitname[0]
'4'
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use stripping and splitting.

First of all, stripping removes all characters from a *set*, you are removing *all `'t'`, `'x'` and `'.'` characters* from the start and end of your string, regardless of order:

```
>>> 'tttx.foox'.strip('.txt')
'foo'
>>> 'tttx.foox'.strip('xt.')
'foo'
```

Secondly, Python offers you the [`os.path` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) for handling paths in a cross-platform and consistent manner:

```
basename = os.path.basename(logfile)
if basename.endswith('.txt'):
    basename = os.path.splitext(basename)[0]
```

You can drop the `str.endswith()` test if you just want to remove *any* extension:

```
basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(logfile))[0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> logfile = r'D:\printLogs\newPrintLogs\4.txt'
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(logfile))[0]
'4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your solutions it helped me but at first I didn't explained question right. 
I founded solution for my problem

```
name = str(logfile)
print ("Part name: " + name.split('\\')[-1].replace('.txt','.zpr'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split and rstrip:

```
print(s.rsplit("\\",1)[1].rstrip(".txt"))
```

But it may be safer to split on the `.`:

```
print(s.rsplit("\\",1)[1].rsplit(".",1)[0])
```

If you `rstrip` or `strip` you could end up removing more than just the `.txt` .

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.4 or later:

```
import pathlib

name = r"D:\printLogs\newPrintLogs\4.txt"
stem = pathlib.Path(name).stem
print(stem) # prints 4
```